# How to run application from war?

Tags: java, class, jar, war, program-entry-point

I have a big war file, that contains many classes with main method.

How I can point Java to run main specific class?

Comment: Check whether, they are packaged into jar file..?

Answer (score 9):

Exactly like running application from jar file:

`java -cp yourwarfile.war com.yourcompany.YourMainClass`

Comment: And if the `.war` file has a manifest with [a Main-Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file#Special-Purpose_Manifest_Headers) defined, running `java -jar yourwarfile.war` should be enough. Works e. g. for [jenkins.war](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins).

Comment: I think because that it is war, not jar file. Paths are different.

Comment: Please post your command line and snippet from `jar -vft yourwar.war | grep YourMainClass`. It really depends on where your class is. If you are on windows use `find "YourMainClass"` instead of `grep`

Comment: Thanks you for useful comment. I found that class in WEB-INF/classes. But in Class-Path in manifest is possible only put jars.

Comment: Although I have never tried this I think you are wrong. Typically java class loader relate equally to jar files and directories. So try `Class-Path: classes` or probably `Class-Path: /classes` or `Class-Path: ./classes`. I believe one of them should work.